# How to use Conditional Operation with Nullable Int

Tags: c#, nullable, conditional-operator

A small problem. Any idea guys why this does not work?

```
int? nullableIntVal = (this.Policy == null) ? null : 1;
```

I am trying to return `null` if the left hand expression is True, else `1`. Seems simple but gives compilation error.

Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `null` and `int`.

If I replace the `null` in `? null : 1` with any valid `int`, then there is no problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes - the compiler can't find an appropriate type for the conditional expression. Ignore the fact that you're assigning it to an `int?` - the compiler doesn't use that information. So the expression is:

```
(this.Policy == null) ? null : 1;
```

What's the type of this expression? The language specification states that it has to be either the type of the second operand or that of the third operand. `null` has no type, so it would have to be `int` (the type of the third operand) - but there's no conversion from `null` to `int`, so it fails.

Cast either of the operands to `int?` and it will work, or use another way of expessing the null value - so any of these:

```
(this.Policy == null) ? (int?) null : 1;

(this.Policy == null) ? null : (int?) 1;

(this.Policy == null) ? default(int?) : 1;

(this.Policy == null) ? new int?() : 1;
```

I agree it's a slight pain that you have to do this.

---

From the C# 3.0 language specification section 7.13:

> The second and third operands of the
>   ?: operator control the type of the
>   conditional expression. Let X and Y be
>   the types of the second and third
>   operands. Then,
>
> - If X and Y are the same type, then this is the type of the conditional
>     expression.
> - Otherwise, if an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from X to Y, but not
>     from Y to X, then Y is the type of the
>     conditional expression.
> - Otherwise, if an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from Y to X, but not
>     from X to Y, then X is the type of the
>     conditional expression.
> - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error
>     occurs.

Comment: insanely precise and accurate.

Comment: @David: It wasn't comprehensive before I had the quote from the language spec. I feel better about it now :)

Comment: @Jon: Very nice answer indeed.  From a stylistic point of view which of your suggestions do you think is best and why?

Comment: @DoctaJonez: I *think* I'd probably use the first form... but each of them is okay... and none of them is particularly nice :(

Comment: Thanks Jon for precise info. However, just for curiosity, why shouldn't the compiler consider the LHS operand as the target type. E.g. considering Z = (expr to check)? X : Y; shouldn't the compiler check whether both X and Y are implicitly convertible to Z, rather than checking within X and Y? In case an implicit conversion doesn't exist, then we would have to cast either X or Y or both to match the type of Z. I guess that would be easier to comprehend.
With my limited knowledge, I did not understand whether this is just by C# design or there's valid reason for which it can't be done.

Comment: @Rajarshi: C# simply doesn't work that way. The compiler shouldn't check that because the language specification says it shouldn't - basically the language is designed so that for the most part, the type of an expression is independent of its context.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
int? nullableIntVal = (this.Policy == null) ? (int?) null : 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try :

```
default( int? );
```

instead of null

Answer (score 1):

This works: `int? nullableIntVal = (this.Policy == null) ? null : (int?)1;`.

Reason (copied from comment):

The error message is because the two branches of the `?:` operator (`null` and `1`) don't have a compatible type. The branches of the new solution (using `null` and `(int?)1`) do.

Comment: an int will implicitally cast to int? - the OP is having problems assigning null to the int?

Comment: The error message is because the two branches of the ?: operator (`null` and `1`) don't have a compatible type. The branches of the new solution (using `null` and `(int?)1`) do.

Comment: I don't think he wants it to be simply 1

Comment: Stephen's answer is correct. The compiler error is raised because C# doesn't find types of `null` and `1` compatible. So by casting `1` to `int?` you make the whole expression compatible with `int?`.

Answer (score 1):

int? i = (true ? new int?() : 1);