# Assign null to decimal using ternary operator

Tags: c#

I am using conversion to `decimal` of a `byte array`, such that it contains either `null` or any other number, stored in byte. The problem here is, when I try to convert a `null` to `Nullable decimal`, it converts it to `zero`. I want it to remain `null`...

```
Convert.ToDecimal(obj.sal== null ? null : System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(obj.sal))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want the result to potentially be null, then you shouldn't be calling `Convert.ToDecimal` - which always returns `decimal`. Instead, you should use:

```
x = obj.sal == null ? (decimal?) null 
                    : Convert.ToDecimal(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(obj.sal));
```

Note that you have to cast the `null` literal to `decimal?` - or use some other form like `default(decimal?)` so that the type of the second operand is `decimal?` - otherwise the compiler won't be able to infer the type of the conditional expression. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881364/problem-using-conditional-operation-with-nullable-int/2881390#2881390) for more details on that.

Answer (score 1):

Because null is of type object (effectively untyped) and you need to assign it to a typed object.

```
x = obj.sal == null ? (decimal?) null 
                : Convert.ToDecimal(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(obj.sal));
```

Comment: That will *never* set `test` to the null value, because `Convert.ToDecimal` has a return type of `decimal`.

Comment: Right, except your "null is of type object" isn't really a good description of what's going on either...